# Cannot handle a Dataflow failed state after wait_to_finish()

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Python script that run a Beam/Dataflow jobs

```
# add config
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
# multiple dataflow processes . . .
# in some process I tryna raise the error to make dataflow job failed

result = p.run()
job_status = result.wait_until_finish()
if job_status == "FAILED":
   # run something else
```

As code above, I am trying to handle a case where Dataflow job might failed which there will be a process in case its failed. But after trying with both Direct runner and Dataflow runner. The job ended at the exception I raised in the function. But for the case if the job success it can handle the `job_status` function e.g. `job_status == "DONE"`

The `wait_until_finish()` will return the final state of the pipeline. So, I think I can make use of this function to handle the failed job but its not working. Any idea?

The log shown in Dataflow console show the Exception I raised and its end like that without running anything in my IF condition

Edit:
I found this from [Dataflow document](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.13.0/_modules/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.html) that it the `wait_til_finish()` handle non-success like this. Not sure if there's an alternative to do this?
[image: Dataflow Doc]

Edit:
What my job actually did is to scrape a data from some website and push it to GCS. The failed part is always on the scraping function where I somehow get 403 by the website in which I have to fix it by running the new Dataflow job manually. I just want to use this to handle to start new job automatically.

```
def scrape_data():
  # scrape data and return a json

def load_to_gcs():
  # dump json to gcs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv)

    # Parse pipeline paramerters
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    id_list = ['aa','bb','cc'] # input param for scrape_data()
    id = p | "init"  >> beam.Create(id_list)
    js = id | "scrape" >> beam.Map(scrape_data)
    js | "load to gcs" >> beam.Map(load_to_gcs)
    result = p.run()
    job_status = result.wait_until_finish()
    if job_status == "FAILED":
       # run something else >> call dataflow api to start new job
```

When its failed (during scrape) the dataflow job will automatically retry for another 4 times and the job will fail. But once its failed, it did not go into the if condition.

Comment: Could you share the code that you have written as it will help to replicate.

Comment: @SandeepMohanty I added my code sample and use case that I am working on

Answer (score 1):

The `DataflowRunner` will throw an error if your pipeline failed (see [this code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py#L1633-L1639)).

You may want to handle that in this way:

```
try:
  result.wait_until_finish()
except:
  # Ignore the exception that may be thrown.
  pass
finally:
  if result.state == 'FAILED':
    # Whatever you need to do about this
    logging.error("Pipeline failed!")
```

Is this a reasonable option?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been raised in this issue tracker. We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/218994234) and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [Link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).